# Angular HttpInterceptor Ignore a Specific HttpErrorResponse Status

Tags: angular

I have an HttpInterceptor that is functional. It has limited responsibilities thus far in that I am only catching HttpErrorResponse. I want status code 404 to just be ignored so that the calling service can decide how to handle the error. I have tried a few different approaches.

If I leave the if block blank, so that the interceptor does nothing, the catch in the service results in a "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable." error message.

If I have the interceptor return an Observable.of(errorResponse), see below, the http.get call's catch is never hit.

If I don't register the interceptor at all, the service works as expected but that doesn't help as I am going to be evolving what this interceptor does.

**Interceptor**

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

return next.handle(request)        
  .catch((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {

    if (errorResponse.status === 404) {
        return Observable.of(errorResponse);
    } else if (errorResponse.status === 401) {
        this.windowRef.location.href = this.windowRef.location.href;
    } else {
        console.error(errorResponse);

        let errorMessage: string = '';

        for (const error of errorResponse.error) {
            errorMessage += error.message + '<br/>';
        }

        return Observable.throw(errorMessage || 'Server Error');
    }
  });
```

}

**Service**

```
return this.http
.get<any>(integrationsApiUrl, { withCredentials: true })
.catch((errorResponse: any) => {      
  if (errorResponse.status === 404) {
    return Observable.throw('No setup data could be found.');
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to **throw** the error response. You should also do that in the else block, BTW, instead of throwing soething other than a response, and thus make the catch block of the service fail.

Comment: Ha, I thought I had tried that too but apparently I didn't. Thanks!